# How to current_time - x (hours only) as a column to an existing Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an existing Spark dataframe `df`. To it, I want to add a column `Hour` that will contain only the hour (no date, no minutes, no seconds).

Also, the hour should be 'x' hours behind the current time.

I did the following for 'x' days behind the current date (date only).

```scala
df.withColumn("date", to_date(date_add(current_date(), -x)))
```

I now want the exact same thing for only Hours. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `interval` to subtract a given number of hours, and `hour` to get the hour only:

```
val x = 1

val df2 = df.withColumn("hour", expr(s"hour(current_timestamp() - interval $x hours)"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, what would I have to do if I wanted to keep the entire timestamp; but having subtracted 'x' hours from it?

Comment: Simply remove hour() @DebapratimChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```
df.withColumn("date", to_date(date_add(current_date(), -x))).withColumn("hour",hour(current_timestamp)-y)
```

here y is number of hours you want to go behind.

Comment: this will result in negative hours if current timestamp is 1AM and y is 6, for example